# Why does the Image move with the browser but doesnt stay centered?

Tags: css

```
#border-search {
    position: relative;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 25% !important;
    width: 100% !important; 
    margin-left: auto !important;
     margin-right: auto !important;
    display: none;
    }   
    #border-search.center img {
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    width: 30%; 
    height: auto;
    }
```

How do i get it to stay centered. ive tried many different things, but they dont work. the display none needs to stay since I need it to show hide the image. What else do i need to add to get thi to work? I want it to stay centered horizontally only

here is js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/matsuiny2004/zffvcvkk/

Comment: Fiddle pls to help u ?

Comment: `position:fixed` makes DIV to stay in place when you scroll

Comment: here is js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/matsuiny2004/zffvcvkk/

Comment: Volvox: I want it to stay centered horizontally only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to center your current `#border-search` inner `img` element with the following change in your CSS, **relative**ly positioning your image with automatic (and equal) left- and right-margins, and making it centered.

```
#border-search {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#border-search img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

The `display: block;` statement is needed for your image to be considered a block element so it can be affected by the margin attributes.

Check the [demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gmnpt3d/) to validate what I just said. :)

Comment: i have added you code it doent seem to do anything.